# How can I receive an XML string value set as part of a JSON object in SpringBoot using REST?

Tags: spring-boot, axios

axios:

```
data = {
    xml:"<div>ABC</div>"
}
```

SpringBoot REST:

```
@PostMapping("/save") 
public R<String> save(@RequestBody String modelBo){
    modelBo_Received = { xml:"ABC" };
}
```

why and how to fix the issue? thanks!

################

```
{
    xml:"<div>ABC</div>"
}
```

shoud be received as expected.